# Error while installing Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, system-installation

I want to install Ubuntu 16.04.2 with Windows 10. I created partions for home , root and swap. After clicking Install, I got following error.  Note: My partition table type is gpt. But cliking F2 , I come to BIOS,not to UEFI.

The partition table format in use on your disks normally requires you to create a separate partition for boot loader code. This partition should be marked for use as a "Reserved BIOS boot area" and should be at least 1 MB in size. Note that this is not the same as a partition mounted on /boot.

If you do not go back to the partitioning menu and correct this error, boot loader installation may fail later, although it may still be possible to install the boot loader to a partition.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: There is an option in your bios to press f2 or del to resume in to UEFI.

Comment: Ok. But what to do? Opening UEFI and install ubuntu?

Comment: When trying to install Ubuntu, your computer is booted in BIOS mode, and it wants to install Ubuntu in the same mode (not UEFI mode). Is this what you want? In that case please create a "Reserved BIOS boot area", a small partition with the `bios_grub` flag. See this link, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace. Otherwise, if you want to install Ubuntu in UEFI mode, you must first boot the computer in UEFI mode. Things are more convenient with Ubuntu in the same boot mode as Windows, and if Windows 10 was installed by the manufacturer  or vendor, I think it is installed in UEFI mode.

Comment: @sudodus I've installed Windows 10 through BIOS,not UEFI. What do you recommend to do next? I've already created partions for home,root and swab? What to do with them?

Comment: install ubuntu in bois mode. otherwise you will have to keep entering system setting and change mode to change os use the same partitions

Comment: @ravery But what to do with that error? I need to create 1mb size partition for that? Please explain

Comment: if you boot in legacy mode, you will not have the error. the 1 mb partition s for efi boot

Comment: @ravery I got that error while installing through BIOS(I pressed F2 while computer's loading). It means that I need to boot through UEFI pressing del button?

Comment: Shrink one of the current partitions to leave space (2 MB) near the head end of the drive and create a partition with the `bios_grub` flag in that drive space according to the link in my previous comment.

Comment: sorry read it wrong, is this a gpt disk? if so, follow the directions stated by sudodus

Comment: @sudodus I got 2MB space from disk D and set label and name of partition as bios_grub. Is it ok?(Your link does not show me how to create bios grub)

Comment: bios_grub is a partition flag, set it in with your partitioner. if making it from the installer, click "use as"  bios_grub should be in the list

Comment: Its' a mess for dual booting since windows 8,you have to work out as I am not familar for windows 10,Their is a keypress for dual boot

Comment: You can use **gparted** to set flags, and `bios_grub` is one of the available flags to set.

Comment: @sudodus Sorry but, I don't have any bios_grub. I have only ex4,ex3 etc...  Bios_grub has to be there with ex4 , ex3's? Please help

Comment: @user202912 -- exit the installer. boot the live CD "try ubuntu".  make the partition using gparted. set the flag. then restart the installer.

Comment: @user202912, please look at the 'answer' which is illustrated with a screenshot.

Comment: @ravery  
Thank you, but there is problem that I've taken 2mb space from disc D and set it to ex4 file system. Was it wrong? But then I flagged it as bios_grub. Then Ubuntu installed successfully,but there is no selection menu to choose Ubuntu. What to do? Please help

Comment: did you install grub to the boot disk? ie the internal drive

Comment: @ravery I don't understand what you mean. I done the following things only: took space from disk D, set it as ex4 , appilied , set the flag. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

I am writing an answer in order to include a screenshot, to make things easier to see.

When trying to install Ubuntu, your computer is booted in BIOS mode, and it wants to install Ubuntu in the same mode (not UEFI mode). Is this what you want? In that case please create a "Reserved BIOS boot area", a small partition with the **`bios_grub`** flag. See this link,

[help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace)

Otherwise, if you want to install Ubuntu in UEFI mode, you must first boot the computer in UEFI mode. Things are more convenient with Ubuntu in the same boot mode as Windows, and if Windows 10 was installed by the manufacturer or vendor, I think it is installed in UEFI mode.

---

The flag is not a file system. Do *not* make any file system. Instead right-click on the partition in gparted and select 'Manage Flags'. Then you get a menu, where you can select the correct flag. I think this screenshot will help.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but there is problem that I've taken 2mb space from disc D and set it to ex4 file system. Was it wrong?  But then I flagged it as bios_grub. Then Ubuntu installed successfully,but there is no selection menu to choose Ubuntu. What to do? Please help

Comment: grub has to be installed to the MBR of the drive that your computer boots from

Comment: If things do not work, I suggest that you remove the file system from the small partition with a `bios_grub` flag. There should be no file system. You can do that in gparted by selecting 'Format to' and select 'cleared', which means no file system. After that you can either reinstall Ubuntu or repair the bootloader (which is much faster, but maybe more complicated to do).

Comment: @ravery How to install grub to MBR? What I forgot to do?

Comment: possibly, but I alsothink he hasn't overwritten the windows bootloader. when prompted where to install grub he needs to select sda (the master MBR). not sda4 (or which ever partition that ubuntu is installed on

Comment: @sudodus You mean that I need to delete all partitions(home,root and swab) and reinstall Ubuntu?

Comment: No, only reinstall. You can keep the partitions and reinstall into the same partitions, but now with a correct small partition with a bios_grub flag.

Comment: @sudodus Hope this is my last comment. The things I need to do is following: 1)Put flash and execute Ubuntu 2) Choose Try Ubuntu and open Gparted 3) Delete that bios_grub and create new one with no file system such as ex4 4)Open installer and format that partitions and install. Am I right?

Comment: @ravery What do you recommend to do? Please help. Steps above are right?

Comment: yes they are. reinstall ubuntu and instal grub to the master MBR when prompted

Comment: Yes, that should work. Maybe a little different with the small partition with a bios_grub flag. You need not delete it. Keep that partition and keep its `bios_grub` flag. Only 'clear' alias remove the file system.